# How do I create a text-wide colored box with proper spacing in the footer of a two-sided KOMA-Script document?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, colorbox

Here is the `scrbook`-class MWE of my current approach:

```
\documentclass[%
    twoside,
    DIV=12,
    headsepline=1.2pt,
    footheight=30pt
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{810081}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{mypurple}}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\scriptsize\sffamily\color{white}}
\ifoot*{}
\cfoot*{}
\lefoot*{\colorbox{mypurple}{%
    \parbox[c][8pt]{\textwidth}{%
        \;\pagemark
        }
    }
}
\rofoot*{\colorbox{mypurple}{%
    \parbox[c][8pt]{\textwidth}{%
        \raggedleft\pagemark\;
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But the resulting colored box doesn't seem to be properly spaced and the output returns an overfull `\hbox` warning: `Overfull \hbox (9.64635pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active`.

[image: Page 1 of MWE]

How can I fix this or what is the more correct approach? Thank you.

Comment: I tested a little and if I use `0.979\textwidth` the warnings vanish and the bar looks OK. But that's most certainly not the TeX way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are unwanted spaces and additionally `\colorbox` adds a colored margin of `\fboxsep`.

```latex
\documentclass[%
    twoside,
    DIV=12,
    headsepline=1.2pt,
    footheight=30pt
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{810081}

\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{mypurple}}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\automark*[section]{}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\scriptsize\sffamily\color{white}}
\ifoot*{}
\cfoot*{}
\lefoot*{\colorbox{mypurple}{%
    \parbox[c][8pt]{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}}{%
        \;\pagemark
        }%
    }%
}
\rofoot*{\colorbox{mypurple}{%
    \parbox[c][8pt]{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}}{%
        \raggedleft\pagemark\;
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: There is an example about coloring the background of the page header in section 18.3 of the KOMA-Script manuals. It should be very easy to adapt it to color the background of the page footer instead of the page header.

Comment: Thank you! Also are you referring to page 454 in [Section 18.3](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf#section.18.3)? Somehow I didn't catch that example when I skimmed through the documentation before, thank you again.

Comment: @AmanuensisFrances Ah, yes, sorry, section 18.3.